# Converting IP Address to an array of bytes C#

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

I'm trying to ping a server based on an IP Address and a port, using the Ping class,
I have to convert the IP Address to an array of bytes, how am I doing it?
I took this method from somewhere

```
 bool IsConnectedToInternet
    {
        get
        {
            Uri url = new Uri("www.abhisheksur.com");
            string pingurl = string.Format("{0}", url.Host);
            string host = pingurl;
            bool result = false;
            Ping p = new Ping();
            try
            {

                PingReply reply = p.Send(host, 3000);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    return true;
            }
            catch { }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

I just have to ping the server based on an IP, not a URL.
Thank you.

Comment: why do you need to convert an IP Address into an array of bytes?

Comment: Whats the problem? Why everyone decreasing the rate?

Comment: @killingswine Because I don't have the URL of the server. I'm pinging a game server.

Comment: Is the "ping based on IP Address" a requirement of the application?

Comment: @JeremyHoward I'm sorry, I don't really understand you, but let me clarify myself again: I have to ping a game server, I have only the IP and port of it, not the URL itself.

Comment: @idish, yes, but why can't you just use the string representation of the IP? Ping.Send will accept that.  See the links in my answer for more options.

Comment: @killingswine Oh seriously? I can just put the IP as a string, it will accept that?

Comment: There's no reason to use Uri at all. `Ping.Send` takes a string representing an IP address or a hostname. And btw you can't ping a specific port.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I know, but where the port is expressed then? I know I have to use the port somewhere.

Comment: @idish, yes, check out the documentation for Ping (second link in my answer below).

Comment: @idish: There's no port in Ping. Ping is based on ICMP not UDP/TCP.

Comment: Your code is not complete. You have `return result` yet you never declared `result` this code wouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the IPAddress class and Ping.Send(IPAddress address) method.  If you're trying to convert from IPAddress to bytes, it offers handy hosttonetwork and networktohost methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb7xxkfx.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just do this:

```
public static bool IsConnectedToInternet
{
    get
    {
        using (var ping = new Ping())
        {
            try
            {
                var reply = ping.Send("173.194.41.168", 3000);
                return reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your code snippet *does not require it*, here is an answer to the question in the title of your post:

You can use [`System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.abhisheksur.com")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostbyname.aspx) to get an array of `IPAdresses` objects representing the addresses of your host. You can then call `GetAddressBytes()` on an individual `IPAddress` object to convert it to an array of bytes.

Comment: I don't know the address, it was just an example that I took from the internet.

Comment: @idish You need to plug in the desired address string in place of the hard-coded constant then.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the documentation for [Ping.Send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dcc2xffs.aspx)